# How to create model instance from button click?

Tags: django

Need help. Just learning Django, with no experience in JS.
How to implement the following feature: in discover_events.html there is an 'Add to calendar' button. I need to add the respective event from the table to the UserCalendar instance. UserCalendar instance is created automatically when the user is created. User is just clicking the button, the event is automatically added to his personal views, like a bookmark, no need to redirect to any other pages and 'Add to calendar' button changes to 'Remove from calendar'.
Update: I've added ajax script and it goes fine to the CBV EventListView, but the last steps of adding an event to the UserCalendar instance doesn't work. When I print the object it stays as events.Event.None

events.models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey("users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="events")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True, editable=False, null=False)
```

users.models.py

```
class UserCalendar(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email  
def post_save_user_receiver(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        UserCalendar.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(post_save_user_receiver, sender=User)
```

discover_events.html

```
{% for event in event_list%}
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="{{ event.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ event.title}}</a></td>
            <td>{{ event.category}}

            </td>
            <td> {% for tag in event.tags.all %}
                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">{{tag.tag}}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ event.organizer}}</td>
            <td>{{ event.event_date_start|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.event_date_finish|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}}</td>
            <td>
                {% if event.event_format == "live" %}
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i><span class="badge badge-pill badge-default"> {{event.event_format}}</span>
                {% elif event.event_format == "online" %}
                <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary"> {{event.event_format
                    }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ event.main_language}}</td>
            <td> 
                <form id="form_id" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit">Add to calendar</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

    $('.likebutton').click(function () {
        var catid;
        catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
        $.ajax(
            {
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'discover_events' %}",
                data: {
                    post_id: catid
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#like' + catid).remove();
                    $('#message').text(data);
                }
            })
    });

</script>
```

events.views.py

```
class EventListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "discover_events.html"
    
  

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(global_visibility=True, event_date_start__gt=datetime.date.today())
        return queryset
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            post_id = request.POST['post_id']
            user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)   
            user.usercalendar.events.add(Event.objects.get(id=post_id))
            user.save()
            print(user.usercalendar.events)
            return HttpResponse("Success!") # Sending an success response
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Request method is not a POST")
```

Comment: you need to use ajax request. if you don't have any idea about that just search "ajax request with django" and review samples.

Comment: Thank you, Saeed, I've made some research and added the ajax call to the template, but now I can't save the event that should be associated, however, I get the proper id and proper user. Any suggestions where to dig?

Answer (score 0):

So, ajax call was made and works properly, the code was update in the question section.  I had to change the view of this library in the HTML template like this

{% for event in request.user.usercalendar.events.all %}